# How to check that Apache / LAMP Ok after using tasksel

Tags: server, apache2, lamp, zoneminder

I'm using Xenial. Installing LAMP Server using tasksel went Ok. I then installed ZoneMinder (including some MySQL configuration). I'm not able to run ZoneMinder. I'm trying to work out where the problem is. When I enter http://127.0.0.1 or http://127.0.1.1 into my Chrome browser, I get "This site can't be reached". Does this mean that Apache / LAMP Server is not Ok? If so, how can I diagnose its problem and then fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'd changed the port (from 80) to 81 that Apache2 was listening on (as per the instructions in https://forums.zoneminder.com/viewtopic.php?t=21721), I needed to put :81 after each of the above http addresses. So obvious when you know how!